# How to add callable link to inline button url in telegram bot api?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-api, node-telegram-bot-api

I need to create inline_keyboard with callable url link in telegram bot api.  The problem is that the telegram does not accept a link similar to 'tel:+99891....', is it possible to somehow add a link that opens the call window to the inline button?

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

You could send a contact instead of a message with [sendContact](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendcontact) instead of [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)